# Visual Studio 2010 randomly crashes when editing XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2010, crash

Visual Studio 2010 RTM randomly crashes when editing XAML in a WPF application. I'm running it on Win 7 fully updated.

The installed extensions/addons are:

- Resharper
- PowerCommands

The crash log is:
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba1fab3
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba1d9ef
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0017f146
Faulting process id: 0xd78
Faulting application start time: 0x01caedc7341e18e3
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll

Anyone experiencing this ? And maybe found an explication ?

Comment: Are you using Release version of VS2010 or Beta?

Comment: It's the release version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was beacause of the AnkhSVN add-on

Comment: Could you specify which version was being used and the exact cause?

Answer (score 1):

Not running VS2010 as administrator did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install [KB980610](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB980610) and/or [KB980920](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB980920) hotfix updates.

I had a similar problem with VS2010 Beta. Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: those hotfixes don't apply to RTM version

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure these addon's are VS2010 RTM compatible?
Also you might want to update your videocard drivers since VS actually makes use of your videocard now so that could cause it to crash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem with VS 2010 an resharper 5. I'm pretty certain its resharper causing the problems. Mine doesn't crash but becomes unresponsive - task manager tells me that it the memory starts rocketing up. Like you, its when I'm editing XAML.

Maybe the crash happens when it runs out of memory

I've brought it up on the resharper forums, but I've not got any replies yet :( You might want to take it up there...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  I uninstalled Resharper to no avail.  Then I realized VS only crashes opening XAML files when I run as administrator.