# Debug Visual Studio Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I am facing exceptions when opening the Visual Studio Designer.

You can find the complete stack trace [here](http://pastebin.com/dHCwTB3E).

I already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581312/editing-xaml-leads-visual-studios-designer-to-crash) where I explained that the crash occurred when passing from XAML to Designer.

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13698442/4384927) suggested to debug the designer with a second instance of Visual Studio.

I've tried the following :

- Open a second instance of Visual Studio, attach the `devenv.exe` process, put a breakpoint on `InitializeComponent` (which is called by the constructor of my `RadWindow`).
- Go to the first instance of Visual Studio, open the designer.

Nothing happened (i.e. the breakpoint isn't reached). Do you have any idea of how can I perform the debug ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have your read [that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514636(v=vs.90).aspx) article?

Comment: @sszarek Yes, I applied the process to my Window and it does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is almost correct. However the process that manages design time WPF rendering varies from Visual Studio version:

Visual Studio 2010  -> `devenv.exe`.
Visual Studio 2012+ -> `XDesProc.exe`.
Visual Studio 2022  -> `WpfSurface.exe`.

**Approach:**

1. Open second Visual Studio with same solution.
2. Set breakpoints in second VS.
3. Build solution (in either VS).
4. *VS2012 and above:*
   Some caching occurs that will prevent hitting beakpoints, so to circumvent, end all running WPF render processes via Windows Task Manager.
5. *(VS2012 and above):*
   To restart the render process, open any xaml document (not the one you wish to debug) in the first VS instance. A new render process starts!
6. In second VS instance, attach to the newly started render process (`XDesProc.exe` / `devenv.exe` / `WpfSurface.exe`)
7. Open xaml document you wish to debug in first VS.
8. Breakpoint hit!

Note: breakpoints should be red to show that they are active. If they are not, then the files used by the debugger does not match the build . If so, stop debugging, end the render process, rebuild and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have any `XDesProc.exe` process running, even when the Designer is opened.

Comment: Oh, didn't see you are using VS2010. In VS2013 it is XDesProc. Just a moment, and i'll correct for VS2010.

Comment: Sorry, But i've uninstalled VS2010 a little while ago, so need to install again, to be able to help. For VS2010 it should be the same procedure, except you attach to `devnev.exe` instead of `XDesProc.exe`. Try closing all open designer files, rebuilding, attaching, and then open file. It is a known question here in the forum: [How to troubleshoot and debug Visual Studio design mode errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698388/how-to-troubleshoot-and-debug-visual-studio-design-mode-errors/13698442#13698442)

Comment: I did the exact process, and it does nothing. Am I missing something ? I put the breakpoint at the beginning of my `RadWindow` constructor.

Comment: It is red. I found an answer which solves the problem of breakpoints, but not the identification of the component : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29890506/4384927

Comment: I have done all of this many times. My Breakpoints dont become red. I Use Vs 2017. Is there an other way ?